# How to get all the tasks from a certain project from Todoist Python API

Tags: python, todoist

I want to get all tasks from a specific task from [Todoist](https://todoist.com/). The documentation says. Taken from the [documentation](https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v1/?python#get-active-tasks) the code for getting all tasks is the following:

```py
from todoist_api_python.api import TodoistAPI

api = TodoistAPI('someToken...')

try:
    tasks = api.get_tasks()
    print(tasks)
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

The documentation does not contain any information about how to get all the tasks from a certain project. Due the reason that I found also another opportunity to get all tasks I am sure there is a way to call all the tasks from a project but it is just not obviously how.

Another way to get all projects from Todoist:

```py
from todoist.api import TodoistAPI

key = "someToken..."
api = TodoistAPI(key)
api.sync()
print(api.state["projects"])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```py
from todoist.api import TodoistAPI

key = "someToken..."
api = TodoistAPI(key)
api.sync()

for project in api.state['items']:
    if(project["project_id"] == someProjectId):
        print(project["content"])
```